# How to post xml data to a xml page

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am trying to post xml code from aspx page to a xml page**(http://../../command.xml)**

Can anyone help me..?

thanks in advance.!!

Comment: Are you trying to POST this data from the server side?  If not then simply set your form method to POST and your action to http://.../command.xml.

Comment: Do you have control over the command.xml page, is it something you've written?

Comment: thanx for reply..!!    But i tried it and i got error as          **HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.**@JoshuaDrake

Comment: yes, I have full control over the command.xml.@JoshuaDrake

Comment: You need to set the server to accept POST for the XML file type, are you using IIS?

Comment: I would of expected you to be posting to an aspx page rather than an XML page, can you explain a little more?